# Centering <h1> in <body> depends on text

Tags: css

Can I calculate with width of `<h1>` (depends on text) and center this `<h1>` horizontally in `<body>`?

Thanks for any help and hint!

Comment: your question isn't very clear - but to center a block-level element like `h1` the usual method is to set its `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`

Comment: Can u post some example please? I tried it, but the <h1> did not move. `position: absolute; top: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: it would be better if you post some code so we can help you better, anyway h1 is a block element so it will take full line width, so in order to position it on the middle, you must decrease its width and then use margin:auto, for example width:50%; then margin:auto;

Comment: If you are using `position: absolute;`, you should use `left: 50%;` and then `transform: translate(-50%)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robin Zigmond is correct in their comment. You can center a block-level element by setting it's `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`. It will appear centered if it's width is not 100% of it's parent container:

```css
h1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

If its width is 100% of its parent container, you could use `text-align` to set the text to `center`:

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```